# Unable to receive form info mail

Tags: php, html

I am attempting to send the details in the fields of a contact form to my mail id. I dont seem to be getting any errors when I hit 
submit but I am not receiving any mail.

Here is my code

```
<?PHP
$email = $_POST["email"];
$to = "myemail@example.com";
$subject = "New Email Address for Mailing List";
$headers = "From: $email\n";
$message = "A visitor to your site has sent the following details to you.\n
Name : $name
Email Address: $email
Phone number: $phone
Message: $message";
$user = "$email";
$usersubject = "Thank You";
$userheaders = "From: myemail@example.com\n";
$usermessage = "Thank you for contacting us.";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
mail($user,$usersubject,$usermessage,$userheaders);
?>

<form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="contact-form-info.php" enctype="text/plain" >
<div id="result" class="result"></div>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name *">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail *">
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone *" onChange="PhoneValidation(this)" ;>
<textarea cols="5" rows="5" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message *"></textarea>
<input type="submit" class="btn-dark" value="SEND">
```

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 0):

Your form is:

- Encoding the data as `text/plain`, which isn't machine readable
- Sending the data as GET not POST (which is what you are trying to read)

Remove the `enctype` attribute and add `method="POST"`

You are also never assigning values to `$name` or `$phone`.